# Postgresql 12 unable to start on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, permissions, postgresql

I am trying to start postgresql 12 on an ubutu 20.04 server using the following command:

```
pg_ctlcluster start 12 main
```

I get the following error from journalctl:

```
A start job for unit postgresql@12-main.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 540857.
Mar 08 13:04:26 server1 postgresql@12-main[107147]: Error: Could not open logfile /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
Mar 08 13:04:26 server1 postgresql@12-main[107134]: Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf"  exited with status 1:
Mar 08 13:04:26 server1 systemd[1]: postgresql@12-main.service: Can't open PID file /run/postgresql/12-main.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
Mar 08 13:04:26 server1 systemd[1]: postgresql@12-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit postgresql@12-main.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'protocol'.
```

I have tried changing the owner of the logfile to postgres and changing the permissions of the directory using`chmod 700 -R /var/log/postgresql`, but I still get the same error.
The file PID file /run/postgresql/12-main.pid does not seem to be created.
How do I fix this issue and start my database?